# Why is everything after the space not printed?

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I created a simple program using the acm library that takes a user inputted string and prints it out in morse. This is the program:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class morse extends Program{
    public void run(){

        String[] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        String[] morse = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
        String word = readLine("Give the word(s) to transcribe: ").toUpperCase();
        println("Morse: ");
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            int k = 0;
            boolean flag = true;
            if(Character.toString(word.charAt(j)).equals(" ")){
                println();
            }else {
                while(!Character.toString(word.charAt(j)).equals(alphabet[k])){
                    if(k < 25){
                        k += 1;
                    }else{
                        println("Letter was not found.");
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag){
                    println(morse[k] + " ");
                }
            j += 1;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

However, every time the string contains a space, everything after the space is not printed. I seriously cant find the reason behind this. Can anyone help me or even point me somewhere ? Thanks

(The letters after the space are all printed as spaces)

Comment: What are `j` and `k` supposed to represent?

Comment: they are just counters

Comment: What do you think they are counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why you define `i` in the `for` loop but never use it. Your main problem is that when you encounter an space you do not increment `j`. I think you have two options:

- increment `j` after you call  `println();` inside the `if`
- drop `j` completely and simply use `i` wherever `j` previously was used (probably the better idea)

---

General recommendation for your code: You are performing too much weird Character and String logic. You could do

- drop the `alphabet`
- get the `char` from the `String` the same way you currently do
- subtract `'A'` from it
- use the resulting `char` as index to access the `morse` array
- drop `k` and the entire `while` loop.

Comment: but i increment j after the the if, which means no matter what it will be increased

Comment: @Gus no, you increment it only inside the `else`.

Comment: @Gus No, you increment `j` inside your `else` block. It's just misleadingly indented.

Comment: i just realised j was inside the else and just badly indented. That did it.

Comment: @luk2302 I didnt quite get what you said

Comment: @Gus you did not get *what*?

Comment: @luk2302 Why substract 'A' and how the rest will work. Im new to it.

Comment: @Gus literally subtract `'A'`: `int index = word.charAt(i) - 'A';`. I could show you how the code looks but I feel it is better if you write the code yourself, the entire for loop (including braces) will only be 8 lines of code.

Comment: @luk2302 yea i dont get why dropping the A would help me.

Comment: @Gus because the result is the correct index, the same thing you previously called `k`, just a lot quicker and shorter, without `while`, without a lot of comparing, etc.

Comment: @luk2302 yea but what if the string contained an 'A' that needed to be transcribed ?

Comment: @Gus: `word.charAt(i) - 'A'` doesnt remove the A from anything. It performs a calculation where the characters are treated as int values and by subtracting the value of 'A' you make sure that you get 0 for 'A', 1 for 'B' etc pp.

Comment: @Gus `'A' - 'A'` is 0, first element of the array gets accessed, all good :) `'B' - 'A'` is 1, etc.